# `x is not None` and `x is (not None)`: are they the same?

Tags: python

Are the following two pieces of code equivalent?

```
if x is not None:
    print("hello")
```

and:

```
if x is (not None):
    print("hello")
```

Comment: No, `not None` is `True`, so second check actually is `if x is True`, while first one resolves into `True`  for any object except `None`

Comment: @GennadyKandaurov But `not None` in the first example doesn't evaluate to `True`. That is because `is not` is an operator, and so Python never evaluates `not None` in the first example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there are not equivalent. `is not` is an operator, the only operator that I know of with whitespace, according to [Python's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#is-not):

> The operators `is` and `is not` test for an object’s identity: `x is y` is true if and only if x and y are the same object. An Object’s identity is determined using the `id()` function. `x is not y` yields the inverse truth value.

In other words, these two expressions are equivalent and always equal to each other:

```
(x is not None) == (not (x is None)) # always returns True
```

In your second example, you are not using the `is not` operator, but the `is` operator and the `not` operator separately. `not None` evaluates to `True`. So we can conclude that the following two expressions are equivalent and are always equal to each other:

```
(x is (not None)) == (x is True) # always returns True
```